# Does FIDO2 keys in Azure AD require P1/P2 licensing

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Does FIDO2 keys in Azure Active Directory(AAD) require P1/P2 licensing? Please let me know which licenses would be required for this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. FIDO authentication just like remaining 2 passwordless authentication methods (Hello and authenticator passwordless) are free.

Please Check this doc to [Enable FIDO2 security key method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-authentication-passwordless-security-key#enable-fido2-security-key-method).